# segmentation fault while running C++ code

Tags: c++, segmentation-fault

I am getting a segmentation fault while running following code :

```
void convert_fix2float(vector<int8_t*>& resultin, vector<vector<float>>& resultout, const float* output_scale){
    
    cout<<"entering fix to float"<<endl;    
    for (size_t ii = 0; ii < 3; ii++) {
    size_t width = shapes.outTensorList[ii].width;
    size_t height = shapes.outTensorList[ii].height;
    size_t channel = shapes.outTensorList[ii].channel;
    size_t sizeOut = channel * width * height;
    for (size_t j = 0; j < sizeOut; j++){
        resultout[ii][j] = resultin[ii][j] * output_scale[ii];
    }
}

cout<<"exiting fix to float"<<endl;

}
```

If I comment out the statement

```
    resultout[ii][j] = resultin[ii][j] * output_scale[ii];
```

segmentation fault disappears.
Can someone help me please to identify the cause of the issue.

Comment: have you tried a debugger?

Comment: how does your call to convert_fix2float look like?

Comment: You need to make sure that `resultout[ii]` has the correct size.

Comment: How do I ensure that resultout[ii] has correct size. It is a vector, so memory will be allocated dynamically. Or do I need to size it and allocate a capacity

Comment: no the vector doesn't size automatically.
when you push_back it increases it's size by 1.
You can also resize, which is probably what you should do here.

Comment: @SunilPuranik `resultout[ii].resize(sizeOut);`

Answer (score 0):

Segmentation failt just means that no memory was prepared.
So one of your elements

- resultout
- resultin
- output_scale

can not be accessed, because no valid memory is accesible at this position.

Answer (score 0):

Operator `operator[]()` in `std::vector` can not create new elements. For creating new elements you can use method `insert()`:

```
resultout.insert(std::vector<float>())
for (size_t j = 0; j < sizeOut; j++)
{
        resultout[ii].insert(resultin[ii][j] * output_scale[ii]);
}
```